# Linearization of a Isometry and a bounded function.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, isometry

I am here to ask for the linearization of the following function, let $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(x)=\Psi(x)+\rho(x)$ where $\Psi$ is a isometry in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\rho$ is a bounded function and $C^1.$ Searching for some information I found the Hartman-Grobman theorem but I think in this case (or for example in $\mathbb{R}^2$) find a linearization for $f$ it can be simpler.

Comment: What do you mean with "linearisation"?

Comment: Find a function $h$ such that $g(x)=h \circ f \circ h^{-1}(x)$ where $g$ is a lineal function.